# GameKit frame work in iPhone

Tags: iphone

I want use GameKit in my application. So I try to add existing framework. But in that list I cant see it...

How can I do this?
pls help me...

Answer (score 2):

I see GameKit in the list of frameworks that appears when I try to add a new framework.  Is the Base SDK for your project set to iPhone Device 3.0?

In any case, you can manually add the framework by choosing Add Other... on the framework selection dialog and navigating to

```
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
```

where you should see GameKit.framework.  Add it to your project, making sure to have its path type be relative to the current SDK.

In the appropriate source files within your project, you'll need to add

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```

to pull in the correct framework header.